# Mysql query with joined tables problems

Tags: mysql

I need help, i must have some basic misunderstanding about joining tables. i have 3 tables, 'item','property','propvalues'
Im trying to list items where the color is black or grey, while the shape is round, for an example. (my tables are more complex, i just tried to make it simple for now. )

```
item
id       category_id
 1            1
 2            1
 3            2
 4            3

property
 id            name
  1           'shape'
  2           'color'

propvalues
id          property_id      item_id    value
 1            1                1          'round'
 2            2                1          'grey'
 3            1                2          'round'
 4            2                2          'black'
 5            1                3          'square'
 6            2                3          'black'
```

i have this query:

```
SELECT item.id FROM item
JOIN propvalues ON item.id=propvalues.item_id
WHERE item.category_id IN (1,2) &&
propvalues.value IN ('black','grey') AND propvalues.value IN ('round')
```

but this gives me no results, while it should output the item id 1 and 2
(because they are both round, one of them grey and the other is black.)
(i also want to include in the where clause the property_id, because later different properties might have the same propvalues.value, so actually the where clause will look like this: )

```
WHERE item.category_id IN(1,2) &&
(propvalues.property_id = 2 && propvalues.value IN ('black','grey')) &&
(propvalues.property_id = 1 && propvalues.value IN ('round'))
```

Can somebody tell me why is not giving me the desired result ? Please explain me what is going on

Comment: why did you use like 
propvalues.value IN ('black','grey') AND propvalues.value IN ('round')???
you should use 
propvalues.value IN ('black','grey','round')

Comment: Because that case i get every item listed which is black or grey or round. But what i want is only those which are round AND black or grey. Also because in the future if i have properties like('inner size', and 'outer size') and property values will be the same for both, like inner size: 25mm, outer size: 25mm, than i would get bad results.

Comment: Show your desired output..

Comment: I want to get the item id, only if it has round propvalue, and also has a color of (grey or black) . This is going to be a query for getting items listed in a webshop, depending on filters selected. I just presented a simplified part of the database which is only needed to solve the problem i have. Im trying to do this list with one query, to make it fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of basic ideas to play around with...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav;

CREATE TABLE eav
(entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute INT NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(entity,attribute)
);

INSERT INTO eav VALUES
(1,1,'round'),
(1,2,'grey'),
(2,1,'round'),
(2,2,'black'),
(3,1,'square'),
(3,2,'black');

SELECT x.entity
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.attribute = 1 THEN x.value END) shape
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.attribute = 2 THEN x.value END) colour
  FROM eav x
 GROUP
    BY x.entity
HAVING shape IN('round')
   AND colour IN('black','grey');

   +--------+-------+--------+
   | entity | shape | colour |
   +--------+-------+--------+
   |      1 | round | grey   |
   |      2 | round | black  |
   +--------+-------+--------+

SELECT x.entity
     , shape.value shape
     , colour.value colour
  FROM eav x
  LEFT 
  JOIN eav shape
    ON shape.entity = x.entity
   AND shape.attribute = 1
  LEFT
  JOIN eav colour
    ON colour.entity = x.entity
   AND colour.attribute = 2;

+--------+--------+--------+
| entity | shape  | colour |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 | round  | grey   |
|      1 | round  | grey   |
|      2 | round  | black  |
|      2 | round  | black  |
|      3 | square | black  |
|      3 | square | black  |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: this is not looking like my db tables

Comment: @Ninet9 It's looking quite a lot like your tables. And has the distinct advantage of being provided as a set of CREATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry. I did some research how things are working, and i can use these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have mutually exclusive `WHERE` conditions:

```
propvalues.value IN ('black','grey') AND propvalues.value IN ('round')
```

The same value can't simultaneously be `'round'` *and* not `'round'`.  Same problem with your later example:

```
(propvalues.property_id = 2 && [...]) &&
(propvalues.property_id = 1 && [...])
```

The same value can't simultaneously be `2` *and* `1`.

Since it's impossible for any one record to satisfy the `WHERE` conditions, no records are returned.

Based on the description of the desired result, it sounds like you want to use an `OR` condition between your groupings of `AND` conditions.  Something like this:

```
(propvalues.property_id = 2 AND propvalues.value IN ('black','grey')) OR
(propvalues.property_id = 1 AND propvalues.value IN ('round'))
```

Comment: Except that I suspect the op wants rows which satisfy both conditions

Comment: (propvalues.property_id = 2 AND propvalues.value IN ('black','grey')) OR
    (propvalues.property_id = 1 AND propvalues.value IN ('round')).     that case if i understand right it gives me every item which is black or grey or round. but i need items which are BLACK OR GREY and also BOTH ROUND

Comment: @Strawberry: Well, since no rows can satisfy both conditions, technically that's what the OP is already getting.

Comment: should i use group by some way to return item 1, and item 2, since both are round, and both grey or black

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying. That is why my query is not working. But there is must be a way to list what i want somehow

Comment: @Ninet9: Interesting, it sounds like what you're looking to do is represent the data in a bit more complex manner.  (Which is probably going to be outside my scope of SQL knowledge, unfortunately.)  The reason you're getting no results *currently* is because you have mutually exclusive conditions.  I'm not really sure what kind of joins or groupings might allow you to have a condition which checks against multiple rows in the overall product of the tables.  (For example: Return Item 1 if one Item 1 row matches one condition *and* another Item 1 row matches another condition.)

Comment: i might need a subquery, but this query will be dynamic, depending on what is passed to the url, and i might have to filter the items by 6 or 7 properties, that means i would need 6 or 7 subquery inserted? i mean like do a select for 'grey' and 'black', and than do another select for 'round' on the previous result ??