# Kind of simple query in mysql but can't solve it

Tags: mysql

I previously posted a question here: [Mysql query with joined tables problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783725/mysql-query-with-joined-tables-problems)
but didn't get good answers, so I thought I break it down to show only the part that gives me a headache, I might get answers faster to this question, and if I can solve this, I can solve the previous problem too.

The values are referring to an `item_id`, and I want to get `item_id`'s where the item is referring to (('good' OR 'bad') AND 'fast')

So `item_id` 1 must be listed, because it is good and also fast
`item_id` 2 should not listed because it is not fast.

The result i want to get

```
item_id
  1
  5
```

if I have a table like this

```
id    item_id    value
1      1        'good'
2      1        'fast'

3      2        'good'
4      2        'slow'

5      3        'good'
6      3        'slow'

7      4        'bad'
8      4        'slow'

9      5        'bad'
10     5        'fast'

11     6        'moderate'
12     6        'fast'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see this is: you want a statement per item, so you aggregate and group by item. Criteria come in the `HAVING` clause.

```
select item_id
from mytable
group by item_id
having count(case when value = 'fast' then 1 end) >= 1
   and count(case when value in ('good','bad') then 1 end) >= 1;
```

(You can also use `sum(case when value = 'fast' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1` or `max(case when value = 'fast' then 1 else 0 end) = 1` or some expression along those lines. `COUNT(expression)` counts expressions that are not null. As I am omitting an `ELSE` branch, a non-matching record results in null and is thus not counted. Some prefer `SUM`, some prefer `COUNT` - it's finally a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: Can you explain why i cant write as: HAVING value IN ('fast') AND HAVING value IN ('good','bad') ? mysql sais: value unknown column in having clause. Is it important to have the count and then when etc.. ? Im just worrying if it takes too long on db having thousands of values

Comment: @Ninet9: You are aggregating records per item (`group by item_id`). After that aggregation you can access the `item_id` and aggregations (sums, counts, maximums, averages, ...), but not the `value`, because there is not one value per item, but several, so which one would you be talking of?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with an `EXISTS` query.

Here's an example:

```
select t1.item_id 
from your_table t1
where t1.value = 'fast' 
and exists (
  select NULL 
  from your_table t2 
  where t2.item_id = t1.item_id 
  and t2.value in ('good','bad')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a item can be good or bad, not both, I would use the simple way:

```
select item_id your_table 
where value in ('good','bad','fast')
group by item_id
having count(*) = 2
```

count should be always 2 in those cases.

Comment: I didnt tell you, but i need to separate the good,bad from the fast, because i need to have more conditions for each property type. like: (value in (good,bad) and property_id = 10) AND (value in('fast')  AND property_id = 10) etc. my tables are much more complicated then the one i presented here

Comment: But the idea was good :-) As good and bad are mutually exclusive, a count of two would have meant good or bad plus fast. Nice thinking.

Comment: Yes i like the idea too. Very Nice. Thank you Mariano